# getting an error in aireplay-ng in kali linux

Tags: kali-linux

when i was testing penetration testing on my router using kali linux, i followed all the steps from this link
http://lewiscomputerhowto.blogspot.in/2014/06/how-to-hack-wpawpa2-wi-fi-with-kali.html
in the step where u have to enter the router's bssid and clint's bssid in aireplay-ng command i m getting the following command

`aireplay-ng -0 2 -a 10:FE:ED:2E:5E:20 -c 08:3E:8E:CC:14:A7 mon7
09:00:33  Waiting for beacon frame (BSSID: 10:FE:ED:2E:5E:20) on channel -1
09:00:33  Couldn't determine current channel for mon7, you should either force the operation with --ignore-negative-one or apply a kernel patch
Please specify an ESSID (-e)`

the channel is -1. but the channel i was capturing was someother channel. i m getting this everytime i try. please help with this -1 channel and how to fix this

Comment: This might be better suited for a [sister website](https://security.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Do exactly what the error message says: re-invoke with the "--ignore-negative-one" long option:

```
aireplay-ng -0 2 --ignore-negative-one -a 10:FE:ED:2E:5E:20 -c 08:3E:8E:CC:14:A7 mon7
```

You may also need to do this:

```
iwconfig mon7 channel *whatever*
```

to get it to use the channel you desire.

Answer (score 0):

Well I got the answer after some browsing. What you need to do is when you start your `wlan0` by using the command

```
airmon-ng start wlan0
```

this command will list some processes which can interrupt the `airmon` in future. So you need to get rid of them first, to get rid of them write the following code

```
airmon-ng check
airmon-ng check kill
airmon-ng start wlan0
```

with above code you will get your `airmon` working properly.

and using `--ignore-negative-one` will not solve your problem because it will ignore the negative channel which you are getting and you will not get wpa handshake.
happy hacking :)